# Unable to removeEventListener in angular directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to prevent the whole page from reloading when I press f5.
I have created a directive that when pressing f5 a button is clicked, this works, however I am not able to remove this event

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpok2b

HTML:

```
<button appClickf5 disabled *ngIf="show">will be clicked if f5</button>
<br/><br/><br/>
<button (click)="show = !show">toggle init/destroy</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickf5]'
})
export class Clickf5Directive  implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.log("init")
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.callback.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.log("ngOnDestroy")
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.callback.bind(this));
  }

  callback(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ((e.code === "F5" || e.key === "F5") && e.ctrlKey === false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this._el.nativeElement.click();
      this.log("element clicked");
    }
  }

  private log(txt){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML+="<br/>"+txt;
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to achieve that with a reactive approach:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickf5]',
})
export class Clickf5Directive implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private destroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
      filter(
        (e: KeyboardEvent) =>
          (e.code === 'F5' || e.key === 'F5') && e.ctrlKey === false
      ),
      tap((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this._el.nativeElement.click();
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
    ).subscribe();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

I've made a live demo with rxjs only, for the first 5 seconds it does catches the events and prevent the refresh. After 5s you can refresh the page:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rfylfi?file=index.ts

To try it, you have to use:

[image]

otherwise the stackblitz app will be reloaded, not the app itself